# Averaging every 10 numbers in a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

How to get an average of every 10 numbers in a big matrix (27x16800).
I can't find the solution
If anyone could help that would be great.

UPD Sorry, I should have been more clear. I have a matrix of recorded values (16800) for 27 subjects. Each subject corresponds to the row; I want to get a new matrix of 27 subjects with 1680 averaged numbers in rows (whereas every "old" 10 numbers in rows will be averaged to 1 "new" mean number).

Comment: "Every 10 numbers" in what direction? What is your expected output size? How do you want to handle the first and last 9 numbers which won't have 10 numbers around them? Please show us a [mcve] to make this question clearer.

Comment: Hi @Vitto ! what do you mean exactly with "every ten numbers"? Along rows? along columns?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I have a matrix of recorded values (16800) for 27 subjects. Each subject corresponds to the row, I want to get a new matrix of 27 subjects with 1680 averaged numbers (whereas every "old" 10 numbers in rows will be averaged to 1 "new" mean number)

Comment: You probably want `n = 10; result = permute(mean(reshape(x.', n, [], size(x,1)), 1), [3 2 1]);` where `x` is the data matrix

Comment: Luis, Thank you so much! That is what I needed.

Comment: `data_mean = squeeze(mean(reshape(data,[27 10 1680]),2));` reshape the data to get a [27x10x1680] array, average along second dimension (gives a [27x1x1680] array) then squeeze the array back to a 2D matrix

Comment: You should note that this is sensitive to where you start. A traditional moving average is (almost) the same size as the original data, whereas your 10 point average could be (hypothetically) wildly different if you shift all the columns by some value not divisible by 10. Also both of Brice and Luis' methods will break if your array length isn't divisible by 10 - which is OK if you can assure that it will be!

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! Wolfie, its divisible by 10, for sure, I got what I wanted. I just have to understand the code, in order to be able to do similar operations myself (I guess).

Comment: Luis Mendo, sorry for being annoying maybe, can you please explain what does `[3 2 1]` part of the code do?

Answer (score 0):

Given a matrix of random data `x`:

```
x = randn(27,16800);
```

you can compute the average over all groups of `n=10` values along the rows in two similar ways as described by [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375345/averaging-every-10-numbers-in-a-matrix-in-matlab#comment93629118_53375345) and [Brice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375345/averaging-every-10-numbers-in-a-matrix-in-matlab#comment93629636_53375345) in comments:

```
y = permute(mean(reshape(x.', n, [], size(x,1)), 1), [3 2 1]); % Luis
y = squeeze(mean(reshape(x,size(x,1),n,[]),2));                % Brice
```

However, as noted by [Wolfie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375345/averaging-every-10-numbers-in-a-matrix-in-matlab#comment93631328_53375345), these work only if the length of the rows is exactly divisible by `n`.

A more general approach can be obtained by convolving:

```
y = conv2(x,ones(1,n)/n,'valid');
y = y(:,1:n:end);
```

Each matrix element in the output of the convolution is the average over `n` values. This result is `n-1` elements shorter than the input. That is, we have computed `n` times as many averages as needed. The second line takes the first of every `n` averages, yielding an output of the expected size.

The convolution yields a result that is different from the other methods by numerical imprecision (max difference is 4.4409e-16 on my machine). This is because `conv2` is implemented using SIMD instructions of your CPU, whereas `mean` likely is not. The convolution approach might be somewhat slower than the other approach, but it is generic and easy to adapt.

Comment: Cris Luengo, thank you so much for the detailed explanation!